# Alternative strategy to CROSS JOIN + LEFT JOIN subquery?

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join a table with **time units** (NB: these are not continuous)

```
Time 1
Time 2
```

…with a table of **departments**…

```
Department 1
Department 2
```

…in order to match with a table of **observations** but select only those of type X…

```
Time unit     Department id       Observation    Type
Time 1        Department 1        6               X
Time 2        Department 2        5               X
Time 2        Department 2        4               Y
```

…to end up with a table like so — where missing observations are filled in with 0s or NULLs

```
Time unit     Department id     Observation
Time 1        Department 1        6
Time 2        Department 1        0
Time 1        Department 2        0
Time 2        Department 2        5
```

This does the job, but it is slow so I am kind of convinced there must be a better way than the following?

```
SELECT timeunits.time_unit, departments.department_id, observations.observation 
FROM timeunits
CROSS JOIN departments
LEFT JOIN   (
    SELECT observations.time_unit, observations.department_id, observations.observation 
    FROM observations
    WHERE observations.type='X'
    ) as observations
ON timeunits.time_unit=observations.time_unit 
AND departments.department_id=observations.department_id
```

**EXPLAIN:**

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref                                         |  rows  | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | time_units   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                        |    200 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | departments  | index | NULL          | PRIMARY     | 4       | NULL                                        |    500 | Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>   | ref   | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 263     | observations.time_units.time_unit,          |        |                                                    |
|    |             |              |       |               |             |         | observations.departments.department_id      |    600 | Using where                                        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | observations | ref   | type          | type        | 258     | const                                       | 100000 | Using index condition                              |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

We have already seen that `type = 'X'` is not too common with the `observations`-table.

Eliminating the sub-query straight-away like this:

```
SELECT timeunits.time_unit, departments.department_id, observations.observation
FROM timeunits
  JOIN departments
  LEFT JOIN observations ON observations.time_unit = timeunits.time_unit 
    AND observations.department_id = departments.department_id
    AND observations.type = 'X'
```

leads to higher execution-times as MySQL can currently only use index on one of the columns in `observations`. As long as this is not `type` the full `observations`-table will be joined (as we explicitly query for all `department_id` and `time_unit` combinations) and just then the columns with differing `type` will be removed => full table scan.

Possible optimization to the sub-query-free statement would be a combined index. Ideally on `department_id`, `time_unit` and `type` as all three are used with equals in the join condition. To reduce storage-overhead we could (and probably should) leave out the column that rules out fewest data.

If we plan on selecting ranges of e.g. `time_unit` later on we should put this column last in the index to be able to use the index best.

Comment: I am too thinking that a subquery would be dragging down performance, but I am afraid that your suggestion runs an order of magnitude slower. My query currently takes ~2 seconds to complete, but I had to terminate your suggested amendment after ~60 seconds. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Added the EXPLAIN output above. :-)

Comment: Intuition would say that `type = 'X'` is less frequent than the combination of `department_id` and `time_unit` in `observations`-table. What are the indexes present in `observations`?

Comment: Agreed. What should it imply? It was therefore I was thinking a subquery quickly reducing the search to the 'type' I am looking was logical step… But there must be a more elegant way… Indexes are on `type`, `department_id` and `time_unit`.

Comment: Is there any combined index on `time_unit` and `department_id`? That could improve speed of my proposal. Otherwise we could try forcing the join to use the index on `type`, but I won't be expecting too much.

Comment: OK. What is meant by combined index?

Comment: Also: the `LEFT JOIN` subquery itself takes ~7 ms and the `(CROSS) JOIN` takes ~1 ms so the bottle neck is really the combination of these two…

Comment: Something like `CREATE INDEX department_id_time_unit ON observations (department_id, time_unit);` depending on data distribution other combinations might be more useful (`time_unit` + `type`?), but generally combined indexes try to improve `SELECT`-speed when said combination of columns is queried.

Comment: That brings me to another question: for `type = 'X'` have you got more different departments or more different time_units with entries? We should try to utilize a join on the other one.

Comment: Combined indexes does not seem to make much of a difference unfortunately. There is an order of magnitude more types than departments and time_units. If that was the question :-) What do you mean by "We should try to utilize a join on the other one."?

Comment: You can use index hints with joins thereby telling MySQL which index to use. But right now I would not expect much of it.